# fail to install package with pip - permission denied

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip

I have problem while trying install 'statistics' package with pip on ubuntu.
running Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.14.17-perform x86_64)

> pip install statistics

i got

> error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/statistics': Permission denied

the full output is :

```
TEMPHOSTNAME:~$ pip install statistics
Downloading/unpacking statistics
Downloading statistics-1.0.3.5.tar.gz
Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_tester/statistics/setup.py) egg_info for package statistics

Downloading/unpacking docutils>=0.3 (from statistics)
Downloading docutils-0.12.tar.gz (1.6MB): 1.6MB downloaded
Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_tester/docutils/setup.py) egg_info for package docutils

warning: no files found matching 'MANIFEST'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'extras'
warning: no previously-included files matching '.cvsignore' found under  directory '*'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory '*'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found under directory '*'
warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found under directory '*'
Installing collected packages: statistics, docutils
Running setup.py install for statistics
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/statistics': Permission denied
Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools,    tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_tester/statistics/setup.py';exec(compile(getat tr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-DT9Slu-record/install-record.txt --single- version-externally-managed --compile:
running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/statistics

copying statistics/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/statistics

running install_lib

creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/statistics

error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/statistics':   Permission denied

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools,  tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_tester/statistics/setup.py';exec(compile(getat tr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-DT9Slu-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_tester/statistics
Storing debug log for failure in /home/tester/.pip/pip.log
```

while trying to use 'sudo'

> sudo pip install statistics

```
TEMPHOSTNAME:~$ sudo pip install statistics
Downloading/unpacking statistics
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement statistics
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for statistics
Storing debug log for failure in /home/tester/.pip/pip.log
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

> EDIT:
>   Soulution:
>   I figure it out. It seems that there was missing http-proxy configurations in the su env, so i set this proxy and finally the installation is done. thanks all anyway.

Comment: pip install require sudo so it won't work without it, but the package you are looking for doesn't exist (or exist under different name), hence the error you got: "Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement statistics"

Comment: Can you give the details of machine you are using, it worked fine with my system - Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: if i understand correctly, it does find the "statistics" when i write "pip install statistics" but it fails with the installation because of permission. when i use sudo suddenly it doesnt find the statistics , else it doesnt find the server.. The machine is running Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.14.17-perform x86_64), its a pc, 2 eth ports are connected, 2 different networks.

Comment: I figure it out. It seems that there was missing http-proxy configurations in the su env, so i set this proxy and finally the installation is done. thanks all anyway.